Ubuntu 24.04 - how to set lower SSL security level?
I've need to enable work of some SHA1 certificate in an app on Ubuntu 24.04. Currently the app throws an error saying Using SSL certificate failed with OpenSSL error - ca md too weak. Google answers that it's need to set a lower SSL security level. There is an instruction worked for Ubuntu 20.04, Ubuntu 22.04, but they doesn't work with 24.04.
The default /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf in Ubuntu 24.04 does not have any strings with SECLEVEL inside at all. Tried to copy the examples listed in that posts. No effect at all. Even if set the level to 0. The error is still appearing. Also tried to specify an temporary configuration file and set OPENSSL_CONF, same result. Seems that something is changed in OpenSSL, so it's ignoring the setup.
Are there ways to enable weak certificates in OpenSSL 3.0.13 used in Ubuntu 24.04?

There are no recent changes in OpenSSL that affect how the config file is read. Setting the OPENSSL_CONF environment variable to point to your config file, and setting SECLEVEL inside it should work just fine in 3.0.13. Perhaps you can share your config file?

Sorry, found the my mistake. I've missed openssl_conf = default_conf in configuration file, so this is why it were not parsed as wanted. Added to its top, and the configuration became working.

The reason was my carelessness. :) I've missed openssl_conf = default_conf in configuration file, so this is why it were not parsed as wanted. Added to its top, and the configuration became working.

do I need to modify /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf? Is there any other operation? Sorry, I am a novice

This is a terrible answer.  I (maybe) need to enable SHA-1 to get a wifi connection to work, but I have no idea where to put the SECLEVEL stuff or what changing openssl_conf is supposed to help with.  Please elaborate!
